# Is there a way to pre render Mobile separately from Desktop?

Tags: reactjs, prerender

I am currently using react-responsive on my website so I can render a different markup on mobile vs desktop. My problem is pre render is only rendering the desktop version and Google mobile usability tool detects our site as not mobile friendly. Thank you!

Comment: Using react-responsive on it's own wont make your website properly mobile responsive,.  Make sure you have the respective meta tags on your website too.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag  Otherwise the mobile phone will just pretend to be a desktop browser,..

Comment: Well. You can read the user agent cookie in you web server layer on url request and serve different html snapshot file based on that for mobile/desktop

Comment: @DmitriiG.  That kind of defeats the whole purpose of making a responsive website.  :)

Comment: @Keith how so? He is talking about the html file before javascript bundle load. After it loads the html is cleared with the up to date render including the responsiveness

Comment: @Keith Thanks! My website is rendering normally (responsive) on all major browsers. The only problem I have is pre render for google bot. Pre render is only caching my desktop version. When testing using the mobile usability tool, pre render is serving the desktop version. Some elements from desktop is removed on mobile (using react responsive) so I can avoid using "display: none" via media query.

Comment: So does your pre-render not have the Meta tags at the top.?  For a responsive website, ideally you don't ship different versions of your website for mobile & desktop, that's the whole point of responsive design.   One of the first things GoogleBot is going to do to find out if your website is mobile friendly, is check the Meta tags..

Comment: @Valkhrist I think we spoke over email, but we (at Prerender.io) have a "mobile adaptive" feature we can turn on for adaptive websites to render desktop and mobile pages separately depending on the incoming user agent and device width. If you have a completely responsive website where the CSS just changes the layout, then that shouldn't be necessary but if you do any user agent or device checking in javascript then we can turn that feature on for you.